# How to install Dvorak Type 2 (ii) German on Ubuntu using Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, dvorak, german

Currently I am using standard Dvorak on Ubuntu 13.10 and Gnome 3.10. Unfortunately, writing Umlauts (ä,ö,ü) in German requires me to switch to QWERTY/QWERTZ frequently or forces me to not write those umlauts (which looks strange to German native speakers).

Is there a way to use Dvorak Type 2, including the umlauts, but otherwise using the standard English layout on Ubuntu with Gnome? I'm a fast typer on standard English Dvorak and would like to avoid fully switching to German Dvorak as this would (at least temporarily) reduce my typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way without the need to install any additional software.

Step 1: In Ubuntu open the keyboard settings and enable Composite Key (System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing -> Composite Key). When you click the value in front of Composite key (Disabled by default), you will get a list of keys to assign. Then choose one of them (Let us choose <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> for example). We will use this key for step 2.

Step 2: Know the key combinations

```
Ä is Right Alt + A + " (double quote)
Ö is Right Alt + O + " (double quote)
Ü is Right Alt + U + " (double quote)
ä is Right Alt + a + " (double quote)
ö is Right Alt + o + " (double quote)
ü is Right Alt + u + " (double quote)
ß is Right Alt + s + s
€ is Right Alt + c + =
```

For example if you want to type the `ü` in `Müller`, first press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, then press <kbd>u</kbd>, then press <kbd>"</kbd> (double quotation mark).

Comment: If you are on Windows, turn on the Numlock and type the following key combinations:

`ä = alt 132
Ä=alt 142
ö=alt 148
Ö=alt 153
ü=alt 129
Ü=alt 154
ß=alt 225`

For example, to type `ü` in `Müller`, first press and hold`Alt`, then press `129` on numeric keypad.